# How to delete space in the input in Python

Tags: python, input, space, startswith

I am writing a program where the user is asked to type in his name.

If the name starts with `a`, `b` or `c`, the program should print `("Your name starts with a, b or c")`.

Unfortunately if the user starts by typing in a space and then typing his name the program thinks the name starts with a space and it automatically prints `"Your name doesn't start with a, b or c"` even if the name starts with these letters.

I want to delete the space in the input now so this problem doesn't occure any longer.

So far I've tried `if name.startswith((" ")): name.replace(" ", "")` 
Thanks for any help!

```
name = input("Hi, who are you?")
if name.startswith((" ")):
    name.replace(" ", "")

if name.startswith(('a', 'b', 'c')):
    print("Your name starts with a, b or c")
    print(name)
else:
    print("Your name doesn't start with a, b or c")
    print(name)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the space using `strip`?

Comment: Strings are immutable. [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns a new string, which you're not using.

Comment: You might want to use [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) or similar.

Comment: Is the test for `a`, `b`, or `c` always going to be single characters? You could say `if name[0] in 'abc':`

Comment: A surprising number of other options. `if re.match(r'^\s*[abc]', name)` works as well, without the need to test for and optionally remove leading spaces.

Comment: @PeterWood: and if you make that `if name.lstrip()[0] in 'abc'` there is no need for the separate `replace`  (Combining your previous suggestions. Maybe throw in a `lower()` to ensure consistency as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String are imutable. No operation on a string will ever change this string

`name.replace(" ", "")` do not modify `name`but return a new string and let `name` unchange

So you can write

```
new_name = name.replace(" ", "")
```

but you can also write

```
name = name.replace(" ", "")
```

In this case, the original string is not modified. But it's name is reused to receive the result of `name.replace(" ", "")`

Wich writing is the best depend on who you ask. I prefer the second one.

Answer (score 2):

As people have stated in the comments, strings are immutable. This means that you can't actually change the value of an existing string - but you **can** create a new string that includes the changes you want to make.

In your case, you are using the [`.replace()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) - this function returns a new string after the replacement has happened. A simple example:

```
str = 'I am a string'
new_string = str.replace('string', 'boat')
```

Note that the variable `new_string` now contains the desired changes - "I am a boat" but the original `str` variable remains unchanged.

To answer your question directly, you'll need to use the variable you created after trimming the whitespace. You can even re-use the same variable:

```
if name.startswith((" ")):
    name = name.replace(" ", "") # override "name" with the new value

if name.startswith(('a', 'b', 'c')):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable and `replace` does not modify the string calling it, but returns a new string which you cold use directly on your code:

```
name = input("Hi, who are you?")

if name.replace(" ", "").startswith(('a', 'b', 'c')):
    print("Your name starts with a, b or c")
    print(name)
else:
    print("Your name doesn't start with a, b or c")
```

You could also create a new variable or just reassign `name`:

```
name = name.replace(" ", "")
```

in case you are going to use it further in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get name as user input and clean    
name = input("Hi, what is your name? ").lower().strip()

# conditional based on intial letter of name
print("Your name starts with a,b or c" if name.startswith(("a", "b", "c")) else "Your name doesn't start with a,b or c")

print(name.capitalize())
```